# Why can't our iPad see all the iTunes-U courses shared from the iMac?

Tags: itunes, ipad, video, sharing, itunes-u

I have 6 courses in iTunes-U loaded into iTunes on my iMac. The latest is WWDC 2012. I can see all those courses on my wife's MacBook, but only the other 5 using the Video app on our iPad.

Can anyone explain this and help me to get all the iTunes-U courses so that I can watch WWDC 2012 on the iPad?

Comment: Have you had any luck?  I downloaded on my PC, and then synced to the iPad, but I can't seem to figure out where to play them at!

Comment: Nothing so far. I watch the ones I can see on the iPad, and use the MacBook for the rest. It feels like a simple bug, maybe from some compatibility in the way bonjour is being used.

Comment: Something I eventually discovered was that when I moved over to using my *personal* ipad, they started working.  It may be that the appleId that downloaded them is the only one that can watch them.  (Or just that iPad 1 can't run them?)

Comment: This iPad is the latest.

Comment: As an update, I think we tracked it down to some of the restrictions being set through the MDM service we use.

Comment: It's November, and I still can't view WWDC 2012 in iTunes U app for iPad (3rd gen). Mark - Did you find a solution? @RonLugge - Did you solve the issue with restrictions?

Comment: @DavidC It turned out that our MDM was misconfigured, and had put a restricted profile onto the device (i. e. turned on restrictions).  As a developer device, it was supposed to be restriction free.  By turning off all the MDM enforced restrictions, I got it to work.